# Decluttering a libraries API

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I am currently writing a wrapper library in C# that wraps a COM object that has a very small and painful to use API and am having a bit of problem with clutter.

This is the first project that I have used TDD and mocking on, so sorry if this isn't really a big problem.  I gave a copy of my library to one of my work mates and the first thing that he noticed was the large amounts of interfaces that where in the API.

I explained to him that because I doing unit testing and mocking I needed the interfaces to stop the tests touching the COM object, he sort of understood but it got me thinking maybe my API is a little bit cluttered making it hard to understand.

My question is - If I am writing a wrapper library where every object touches the COM API somewhere, what is the best way to declutter my API and still be able to test the code.

Should I be using abstract classes instead of interfaces for most things? or should I just hide the interfaces that are only for mocking reasons away in a namespace somewhere?

Comment: Do interfeces smell as bad as I imagine?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found having an exposed API to be a big deal beyond the comment to a coworker.  Your coworker will appreciate the flexibility with which your application will change as you move forward way more than the "cluttered" API.

I wouldn't worry about it and move on with your life.

As for mocking, I definitely prefer interfaces over abstract classes.  You'll find the more you go into this that you'll write *composed* applications instead of *inherited* ones.  This is due to the fact that you want to keep your objects small and the dependencies few so the testing doesn't turn into a big mess.

Answer (score 0):

If an interface is there only for mocking purposes, I would suggest making it internal.  You can then apply InternalsVisibleToAttribute to your wrapper library to expose the internal interfaces to your tests.